# Uncaught Invariant Violation: A state mutation was detected between dispatches when using arrayMove

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-state, reducers, react-hoc

I'm trying to build a React/Redux app and I am a beginner. I want to use the React Sortable HOC to have a rearrangeable list but I cannot get the new arrangement to stick.
I have a functional component where I get the list of items. The item structure is like this:
items [ {name, courseList}, {name, courseList}, ...].

To populate the table I make an api call and update the prop variable using MapStateToProps. Here's a bit of code:

```
function CoursesPage({
  student,
  studentCourses,
  loadStudentCourses,
  updateCoursesOrder,
  ...props
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (studentCourses.length === 0) {
      loadStudentCourses(student.id).catch((error) => {
        alert("Loading student courses failed" + error);
      });
    }
  }, []);
...
}
```

and this is the mapStateToProps function:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    student: state.student,
    studentCourses: state.studentCourses,
  };
}
```

This bit works fine, and everything appears.
The problem is when I try to rearrange and save it in onSortEnd function:

```
  function onSortEnd({ oldIndex, newIndex, collection }) {
    const newCollections = [...studentCourses];

    newCollections[collection].courseList = arrayMove(
      newCollections[collection].courseList,
      oldIndex,
      newIndex
    );

    updateCoursesOrder(newCollections);
  }
```

The newCollection gets populated and modified correctly and I am calling updateCoursesOrder with  the items correctly arranged. That function is an action that calls a dispatch.

```
export function updateCoursesOrder(courseList) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(setNewCourseOrderSuccess(courseList));
  };
}

export function setNewCourseOrderSuccess(studentCourses) {
  return { type: types.SET_NEW_COURSE_ORDER, studentCourses };
}
```

Using the debugger I can see that the code is running well up till the dispatch return from setNewCourseOrderSuccess().

This should go to the reducer, but instead throws an error: Uncaught Invariant Violation: A state mutation was detected between dispatches.

This is how the reducer looks like:

```
export default function courseReducer(
  state = initialState.studentCourses,
  action
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case type.LOAD_STUDENT_COURSES_SUCCESS:
      return action.studentCourses;
    case type.SET_NEW_COURSE_ORDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        studentCourses: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

How could I solve this issue?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
const newCollections = [...studentCourses];

newCollections[collection].courseList =
```

Although `newCollections` is a new array, it's only a shallow copy of the `studentCourses`; the array items are not clones, they're references to current objects in state. So, assigning to a `courseList` property of one of those objects is mutating the state.

Replace the object at the index instead of mutating it:

```
function onSortEnd({ oldIndex, newIndex, collection }) {
    updateCoursesOrder(studentCourses.map((item, i) => i !== collection ? item : ({
        ...item,
        courseList: arrayMove(item.courseList, oldIndex, newIndex)
    })));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for explaining and for the fix! It's working properly now

Comment: Thank you @DorianOlarescu for the above post.

Comment: I spent hours trouble shooting this error
```text
Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'stats.stats_trade.0.Net P/L'.  This may cause incorrect behavior. (https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state)
    at invariant (immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:25:1)
```
I realized that the nested array object saved to redux after using the spread operator [...array] was only shallow copied. 
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObject))  works for deep copy.